# Apply custom appearance to individual model fragments in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In the viewable, the model has three leaf nodes that are named “Solid1” but have a parent name of “Tread”, how do I search by parent name to get the dbId?

Following the answer from [Default material for model in Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475341/default-material-for-model-in-forge-viewer/54518720#54518720) I can see that we can set a color. Is it possible to instead apply a texture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The **Viewer** has a **search()** function so you can search for any component based on its properties. You can then go up and down the instance tree to go from **Thread** to **Solid1** or vice versa. See e.g.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override

Yes, you can also use texture for materials. See e.g. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material.js#L273 
That code is used in this sample https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=58c7ae474c6d400bfa5aaf37
Just enable the "**Material**" extension by clicking on it, then you will be able to assign textured materials to faces.

[image]